# Random error "Failed to update header with correct duration."

Tags: linux, bash, nginx, ffmpeg

I have a bash script that triggers a ffmpeg command, the loop strangely doesn't start again after the error below randomly occurs :

```
Failed to update header with correct duration.
Failed to update header with correct filesize.
```

I looked up everywhere, no luck. I dont mind the error, just why won't the bash loop work correctly and relaunch the command ?

I am running a nginx server where I push the stream to, here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

until ffmpeg -thread_queue_size 512 -re -I "external URL" -vcodec copy -vprofile baseline -acodec aac -strict -2 -f flv "nginx URL"; do
    echo "restarting ffmpeg command"
    sleep 1
done
```

Thank you !

Comment: Because ffmpeg is not exiting. It continues to run after printing the warning.

Comment: So do you think I should fix the error or force ffmpeg to exit. How do I make ffmpeg exit after printing the warning ?

Comment: Why would you want it to exit?

Comment: @szatmary so it would loop back if this error occurs, I have no control over this error because it randomly happens and the streaming stops.